# Transforming navigation bar to a fixed header over horizontal parallax website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

The title may seem a bit peculiar but I will try explain as best as possible so confusion is minimized.

Currently I am using the FullPage.js plugin with my website to create a horizontal 'slide' effect. Check the website out currently to see what I mean. http://carrotcrunchpvp.comule.com/

As you can see the navigation bar is slap bang in the middle of the page when you enter where everything is rotated and such. When I slide to the right using the arrow, I want the navigation bar to 'push' out so the Ethos link goes to the top left, privacy policy link goes adjacent to this (horizontally), then the path to healing. Then the logo will shift directly upward to form the middle of the navigation bar. NZ catholic church will shimmy to the right and up adjacent to the logo, contact us will go slightly further to the right and the about page will reach the far right of the navigation bar which will be all located at the top of the page. This will essentially be creating a header navigation bar

Look at illustration for a better idea:

[image]

The black lines are the path of transformations. However it's not as easy as it seems, I could do this with CSS3 transformations too...

Now my problems, I'm capable with CSS, but my Jquery and Javascript knowledge is lacking. I'm unsure as to how to approach this. This is because I only want this transformation to **occur when clicking from the homepage to the next page** or one of the other pages with more content. It will essentially be turning into a fixed header. However when I go back to the homepage it will need to animate backwards to the original navigation bar...

How would you go about this? This is a task my I.T teacher has set me to do over the holidays and I'm struggling to figure how to logically do this.

If I've missed anything or you're still confused on what I want to achieve, feel free to comment and I will try clarify. To the mods, it's a subjective topic, I'll agree - but it's a topic which spreads creativity and shouldn't be frowned upon and looked at for closure - IMO...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the callbacks fullPage.js provides such as [`afterSlideLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex) or [`afterSlideLeave`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onslideleave-anchorlink-index-slideindex-direction).

If you do not want to deal with javascript at all, notice how fullPage.js is updating the class `fp-viewing-xxxx` in your `body` element.

You can use it to fire your animations depending on the active class.

- When you load the site it will be empty.
- Going to the second slide will add the class `fp-viewing-horizontal-1` in your case
- Going back to the home again will now load `fp-viewing-horizontal`.

In css you could something like:

```
body .menu,
body.fp-viewing-horizontal .menu{
  //your home menu styles/animations
}

body.fp-viewing-horizontal-1 .menu,
body.fp-viewing-horizontal-2 .menu,
body.fp-viewing-horizontal-3 .menu,
body.fp-viewing-horizontal-4 .menu,
body.fp-viewing-horizontal-5 .menu,
body.fp-viewing-horizontal-6 .menu,
body.fp-viewing-horizontal-7 .menu{
  //your fixed menu styles/animations
}
```